# Plot decision boundaries with scikit-learn for mutlidimensioanl dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I am trying to compare some classifiers on my own dataset: A set of 1000 faces and non-faces images. Each sample in my dataset is a row of `361 features (19 x 19 pixel)`.

I tried to follow this example: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_iris.html
. but the problem is that this example is working only for 2-dimensional features.

Is there a way to adapt the code in the example to work with 361-dimensional dataset ?

Comment: Ehm, so how are you going to plot a 360+ dimensional space?